# Why can't I delete an method/attribute from a Tkinter Window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to remove a method from an class instance derived from a Tkinter window using the `delattr` built in function. However, I get the following error. What am I doing wrong?

Error :

```
AttributeError: Class instance has no attribute 'wm_title'
```

An example :

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Class (tk.Tk) :
    def __init__ (self) :
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        # The method is clearly there, seeing as this works.
        self.wm_title('')

        # This raises an AttributeError.
        delattr(self, 'wm_title')


c = Class()
c.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't delete a class method that way because class methods are properties of classes, not objects.

When you invoke a method via `object.method()`, python is actually calling `Class.method(object)`.  (This is also why you must declare a `self` argument in class methods, yet you do not actually pass any value for `self` when invoking that method.)

If you want, you could call `del Class.wm_title`.  (I'm not sure why you want to, though.)